# Update one table with values from another table using select statement

Tags: mysql

I want to update the `ClaimNos` for a few `declarationNos` in table1 according to table2.

```
UPDATE sg_report
SET    ClaimNo = (
  SELECT  MAX( dummy.ClaimNo ) as ClaimNo 
  FROM dummy
  WHERE ClaimNo REGEXP  '^[0-9]+$' and sg_report.DeclarationNo = dummy.DeclarationNo
) 
WHERE dummy.DeclarationNo = (
  SELECT DISTINCT dummy.DeclarationNo
  FROM dummy
  WHERE dummy.DeclarationNo LIKE  '30%'
)
```

This query doesnt give any errors but it doesnt work either. Whats wrong ?

Comment: Whats the regular expression and whats the purpose of it?

Comment: the coloum claimNo has some junk text values so the regex fetchs a number from all that junk text which is the claimNo

Comment: If you want max of claim no. then your query should have been like this : SELECT MAX( dummy.ClaimNo REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' ) as ClaimNo FROM dummy WHERE sg_report.DeclarationNo = dummy.DeclarationNo. Also, make sure your second inner query should not be returning more than one value coz you have used LIKE '30%' which could result in more than 1 values. If that the case use IN operator instead of = operator, check this line : dummy.DeclarationNo In instead of dummy.DeclarationNo =

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you copied your query wrong.  You have `WHERE dummy.DeclarationNo` and I suspect you actually have `WHERE sg_report.DeclarationNo`.

Paresh J is correct that your `WHERE` statement should include `IN` rather than an equal statement since it could return multiple rows.

But the answer to your question I suspect is related to the data type.  I created a sample database and ran the following query and it worked just fine.  I actually spent a while trying to debug it since it wasn't updating anything until I realized that **there was nothing to update**!

```
UPDATE sg_report
SET    ClaimNo = (
  SELECT  MAX( dummy.ClaimNo ) as ClaimNo 
  FROM dummy
  WHERE ClaimNo REGEXP  '^[0-9]+$' AND sg_report.DeclarationNo = dummy.DeclarationNo
)
WHERE sg_report.DeclarationNo IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT dummy.DeclarationNo
  FROM dummy
  WHERE dummy.DeclarationNo LIKE '2%'
)
```